# User can view my report in a browser, but gets not authorized when using the Power BI Mobile application

Tags: powerbi

A user at my company when opening a dashboard from the Power BI Mobile Windows application receives a “not authorized … contact administrator” error message, however it comes up fine in a browser.

I had to share the dashboard report with him before he could view it in the application.

I hoped someone might have an idea what the issue could be.

Thank you so much.

EDIT: It actually appears this is a global issue with all users. No one can see this report in Power BI Mobile. Everyone receives the error, "The report shown in this tile doesn't exist or you don't have permission to view it.". However viewing it in Chrome or Edge browser it shows correctly.

[Report from Power BI Mobile app for Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWxfw.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by: Power BI Windows application? Power BI Desktop? Or webBrowser we workspaces?

Comment: The user is using the Power BI Mobile app for end-users not the Power BI Desktop. That is where he is receiving the "not authorized …" message. He can see the report when using Chrome or Edge browser (at https://app.powerbi.com/home)  I have confirmed he is using the same user account, and can see all other reports without issue except this one.